# How to replace a value in a list while input?

Tags: python, input

I have a string in an input that needs to be split into separate values and left in a list.
I am using the following construct to enter values. How can the value `-1` be noticed on a variable `var`?

```
import sys
readline = sys.stdin.readline
var = 10**5

current_line = list(map(int, readline().split()))
```

Example input:

```
-1 3 0 -1 4 5
```

Required value `current_line`:

```
[var, 3, 0, var, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple list comprehension for that:

```
x = [-1, 3, 0, -1, 4, 5]

var = 10**5

# loop through all elements and if the element is -1 replace it with var, else keep the old element
x = [var if i == -1 else i for i in x]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check for `-1`s as you go and replace them with `var`:

```
current_line = [var if i == -1 else i for i in map(int, readline().split())]
```

`var if i == -1 else i` is [Python's ternary conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/364696) (more precisely "conditional expression"), so `-1` values get replaced, and all others are kept unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `-1` with `var` as you iterate over the list of values.

```
current_line = [var if x == -1 else x for x in map(int, readline().split())]
```

I'd probably forgo the use of `map` altogether in this case. No use converting `'-1'` to `-1` if you're going to immediately discard the `int` value anyway.

```
current_line = [var if x == '-1' else int(x) for x in readline().split()]
```

For a different emphasis, negate the comparison.

```
current_line = [int(x) if x != '-1' else var for x in readline().split()]
```